# Android Studio Bumblebee can't detect androidx package

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-studio-bumblebee

I was using components from `androidx` package in a project. After upgrading my Android Studio from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee, the androidx components are not detected in the IDE. It suggests me to import them, but when I import them following the suggestion in IDE, it imports the same components from `android` package.

[package imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O5k6.png)
As you can see in the screenshot, `androidx` components are greyed out but they are being used in this class.

[component in usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfMdr.png) And if I don't import from `android` package, the components are shown as error.

However, the project still compiles and runs without any problem. But the incorrect errors are annoying to work with.

I've tried setting the following in `gradle.properties`:

`android.useAndroidX=true`

`android.enableJetifier=false`

It doesn't solve the problem. Is there anything else that I can do to use my androidx components in Bumblebee?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Invalidate caches, restart

Comment: @cmak tried it, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade gradle plugin to version 7.3.1